# Saving a StackedInline foreign keyed model before primary model in Django Admin

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have four models with the relationships

```
Model PagetTemplate(models.Model):
    pass

Model TextKey(models.Model):
    page_template = models.ForeignKey(PageTemplate, related_name='text_keys')


Model Page(models.Model):
    page_template = models.ForeignKey(Pagetemplate, related_name='pages')

Model Text(models.Model):
    key = models.ForeignKey(TextKey, related_name='text_fields')
    page = models.ForeignKey(Page, related_name='text_fields')
```

the relation is like this:

```
                            PageTemplate
                                /\
                               /  \
                              /    \
                       TextKey      Page
                              \    /
                               \  /
                                \/
                               Text
```

In the validation for page (In the `clean` method), I check that [key for key in page.page_template.text_keys] and `[text_field.key for text_field in page.text_fields]` match up so that all text keys are filled in my a text. The problem I am having is that at the time the `clean` is called, `page.text_fields` is empty. The admin code looks like.

```
class TextInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Text
    extra = 0

class PageAdmin(DebugModelAdmin):
    inlines = [TextInline]

admin.site.register(Page, PageAdmin)
```

I wrapped `admin.ModelAdmin` in a logging class and know that I have the information I need when `ModelAdmin.add_view` is called but is overriding this the right thing to do or is there some option/method that would be better to override that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at S. Lott's sagacious advice on various django related threads, I decided to write an app to do this myself instead of forcing the django admin to do something that it wasn't meant to do. I would honestly just download a decent CMS for django but the ones that I can find either suck (their code is riddled with typechecking, indented with tabs, etc) or don't work on 1.2, so i'm rolling my own.